# NodeJs - nested JSON POST input

Tags: json, node.js, postman

I need to read nested JSON data in my Node.js server sent with a POST form.

For testing I'm using Postman with a POST request at `127.0.0.1:8080/extractByCenter`, with `Header Content-Type = application/json`
and Body as "raw" `JSON (application/json)` with the following data:

```
{
    "center": {
        "lng":17.4152,
        "lat":40.4479
        },
    "radius":20
}
```

My main .js file launched with node is very simple:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//------------------------------------
//Configuration
//------------------------------------
var config = require('./config.js');
app.use(morgan('dev')); //remove dev at the end of development
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//------------------------------------
//Routes
//------------------------------------
app.use('/',    require('./routes/maprouter.js'));

//------------------------------------
//Server Start
//------------------------------------
mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE);
app.listen(config.SERVICE_PORT);
console.log('server start at port ' + config.SERVICE_PORT);
```

Where the `maprouter.js` just use a function of the MapManager.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MapManager = require("../managers/MapManager");

router.route('/extractByCenter').
    post(function(req,res){
        MapManager.extractByCenter(req.center,req.radius,function(err,data){
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 200,
                data: data
            });
        });
    });
```

This function just takes the JSON data `center` and `radius` and it performs the query on the DB.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var config = require('../config.js');
var GeoJSON = require('../models/GeoJSON.js');

var Manager = {
    extractByCenter: function(center,radius,callback){
        var query = {
            'coordinates' : {
                $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: "Point" ,
                    coordinates: [ center.lng , center.lat ]
                },
                $maxDistance: radius,
                $minDistance: 0
                }
            }
        };
        GeoJSON.find(query,'-__v -_id',callback);
    }
}

module["exports"] = Manager;
```

The problem is the reading of the center data `[ center.lng , center.lat ]`:
I have a *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of undefined"*

Why *center.lng* (and surely also *center.lat*) doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post to express, the body parser puts the request body into the body object. You're trying to access it off of req.center and req.radius instead of req.body.center, req.body.radius.

`req.body.center, req.body.radius`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MapManager = require("../managers/MapManager");

router.route('/extractByCenter').
    post(function(req,res){
        MapManager.extractByCenter(req.body.center,req.body.radius,function(err,data){
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 200,
            data: data
        });
    });
});
```

Ninja Edit:

Try doing a console.log of the req object so you can see all of the different things that it contains.

Answer (score 3):

The bodyParser places things on req.body, not on req.  So change your code to be `req.body.center` and `req.body.radius` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
req.body
```

make sure that body parser has to be there